# process.exit() terminates the program before the execution is not complete in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I'm having an issue to terminate the process with `process.exit()`.

```
const main = async () => {

// do something here

try {

    await doOperationA()
} catch (error) {

} finally {
    process.exit()
}
}

main();

**another file**


const writeToCsv = async (result) => {

    // write result to the csv file
    for (let item of result){
        csvWriter.writeRecords()
    }

}

const doOperationA = async() => {
    // do something
    await anotherAsyncOperation();

    await writeToCsv(result)
    return
}
```

When this code runs, `process.exit()` terminates the execution **before** the CSV output operation completes. How can this program be safely terminated after everything is done?

My solution was changing `writeToCsv()` to this

```
const writeToCsv = async (result) => {

    // write result to the csv file
    for (let item of result){
        await csvWriter.writeRecords()
    }
    return 
}
```

basically, put `return` and `await` - it seems like `process.exit()` works as expected...? But I'm not sure so if you can provide the reason why it works (and why the previous one didn't work), that would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `main()` function is `async`, but you call it without `await`

Comment: I don't get what is the problem, seems like you solved it already

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `process.exit()` (e.g. to return a specific code)? In most cases you can just omit it, and Node will exit when there are no more async tasks.

Comment: Hi edemaine, thank you for your comment. Without process.exit(), I need to use ctl+c - it's ok to do that on my local environment but this program should work on VM as a scheduled job, so I thought process.exit() would be needed.

Comment: Hi Konrad, thank you for the comment. I solved it... maybe? It the solution is the right thing to do, I would like to know why it works and why it didn't work for better understanding (since I put return and await as an impulsive attempt...)

Comment: Marking a function as `async` doesn't automatically make it wait for the other async functions. Your `writeToCsv` resolves immediately if you don't use `await` in the loop